# Unknown crash when using dynamic char array after several times

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, char

What are the main causes that produce crashing in a program when doing dynamic memory?

I have a class, with the following public pointer defined in the .h file:

```
char *data;
```

My program has a main function, where I create sequentially objects of this class, and in this creation I do the memory part:

```
data = new char[dataSize];
```

The main function, executed once (the objetcs are created 10 times) works perfectly. However, when I run the main function again (without closing the program), there is a moment that the instruction **data = new char[dataSize]** crashes the program (execution ends suddenly, so I can not debug or see anything).

By the way, the pointer is initiliaze to NULL everytime the object is created (befor the memory part).

This is the code. Firstly, the main function, which is executed like 20 times with different objects:

```
CBinFileHwd validEpsData1;

validEpsData.loadFile(lpcTheFile3,dwFileSize,FT_BIT);
```

So the next lines of the function will be the same as above, but instead of validEpsData1, it will be validEpsData2, and up to 18 times (validEpsData17).

Code of the class (.c):

```
CBinFileHwd::CBinFileHwd()
{
    status = FILE_NOT_LOADED;
    fileType = FT_UNKNOWN;
    data = NULL;
    currentPos = 0;
    dataSize = 0;
}
CBinFileHwd::~CBinFileHwd()
{
    if (data!=NULL) {
        delete [] data;
        data= NULL;
    }
    fileType = FT_UNKNOWN;
    status = FILE_NOT_LOADED;
}
int CBinFileHwd::loadFile(const char *fileName, const unsigned long int &maxSize, const E_FILE_TYPE &fType)
{
    // Open input file
    int fd = open(fileName,O_RDONLY | O_BINARY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        char  logString[1024];
        sprintf(logString,"Error opening file %s",fileName);
        logMessage(logString, false, false, false);

        fileType = FT_UNKNOWN;
        status = FILE_NOT_LOADED;
        return -1;
    }

    dataSize = lseek(fd,0,SEEK_END);
    lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);

    if (maxSize < dataSize) {
        dataSize = maxSize;
    }
    data = new char[dataSize];
    unsigned long int dataRead = 0;

    while (dataRead < dataSize){
        dataRead += read(fd, &data[dataRead], BLOCK_SIZE);
    }
    // Close file
    close(fd);

    status = FILE_LOADED;
    fileType = fType;
    if (maxSize != dataSize) {
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Code of the class(.h):

```
typedef enum{FT_BIT,FT_INT,FT_DOUBLE, FT_UNKNOWN} E_FILE_TYPE;

class CBinFileHwd
{
    private:
        static const int BLOCK_SIZE = 4096;
        typedef enum{FILE_NOT_LOADED, FILE_LOADED} E_STATUS;
        E_STATUS status;
        E_FILE_TYPE fileType;
        char *data;
        unsigned long int currentPos;
        unsigned long int dataSize;
    public:

        CBinFileHwd();
        ~CBinFileHwd();
    int loadFile(const char *fileName, const unsigned long int &maxSize, const E_FILE_TYPE &fType);
};
```

Comment: I believe that you'll need to post more code. Your main function, for example.

Comment: do you delete the memory? If yes, do you use ``delete[]``?

Comment: @Hyndrix. Yes, I delete the memory in the destructor, using delete[] as you pointed out.

Comment: @Streppel, I will try to poste a summarized version of the code.

Comment: I bet this is due to stack corruption for some reason. Can't say for sure without seeing the code.

Comment: What do you mean by _run the main function again (without closing the program)_?

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay: goto? black magic?

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay, sorry for the bad explanation. I was trying to say that the problem appears only when I create a lot of objects. If I create only 10 objetcs, it works perfectly, but when I create more than 18, it crashes. It seems a stack issue but I don't know where to look for.

Comment: @cuartango, we don't know either. Post the code to get the answer.

Comment: @maverik, there you have the code uploaded.

Comment: still using char and printf in c++??

Comment: @cuartango, note the `read()` may return `-1` in case of error. Also note that between the line where file size calculated and the lines where file is read the file itself can be changed and you will likely get endless loop.

Comment: @cuartango, also calling `validEpsData.loadFile();` several times you'll get memory leak because the destructor will be called once and only will only delete last allocated buffer.

Comment: @maverik, it does not appear in the code, but the constructor is called all the times the different objects are created (I will change the code now), and also I can tell that the destructor is called the same number of times. So it seems that the object is reserving space which is already allocated. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

This could happen because:

1. double free because of improper copy constructor and assignment operator written for this class. Due to this multiple objects might be pointing to the same dynamic memory allocation. constructor and destructor looks ok if your input data size are not more than 128 byte length which is your allocation size.
2. This could also be because of heap memory corruption in your program and this piece of code might be just victim/ after effect of elsewhere actual corruption.

However once you post your code we might be better position to find out the cause of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

It looks your program is crashing because of point 1 mentioned in my above answer.

There seems to be one more memory leak problem as "data" is member variable of your class and once you calling the loadFile() function multiple time, data is getting overwritten by the newer memory address. This is also a big problem in your code.

probably you would like to do the check before allocating "data" memory.

```
int CBinFileHwd::loadFile
{
 ...................
 if(data != nullptr) {
   data = new char[dataSize];
}
    unsigned long int dataRead = 0;
..........................
}
```

Comment: I agree with you, it seems that the problem is the memory overwritten. I have tried putting the delete [] at the end of loadFile function (instead of in the destructor), and I don't get the error, but the program don't perform as I expected. Is there anyway to delete the memory?

Comment: @cuartango, I think you should first check whether "data" is nullptr. If it is not nullptr, then you should allocate as usual. If it is equal to nullptr, then you should first delete and then allocate. If you can know the maximum value, then you can allocate the memory in the constructor and may reuse it in the any member function of this class.At the end in the destructor you can delete the memory as you are doing now. I think this is best you can do it in your existing implementation. However i would also suggest you to try to re implement your logic in iostream/string class if possible.

Comment: I have tried what you said but still crashes. I have found out that if I do not use any delete, the program works. It seems that the automatic destructor inside Borland (it is muy compiler) is deleting the memory reserved. I am also sure of this because in the windows task manager there is now memory rising in the processes when I execute this part of the program.

Comment: @cuartango, no compiler does automatic memory deletion
for raw pointers in C++. Program needs to take care about
memory management. Task Manager does not start showing
the rise of memory usage immediately as it depends on lot
of other factor(commit/private).Its not direct mapping 
of heap memory allocation and task manager information
regarding this. So not deleting the memory is not correct
way for this even though your program works. Memory leak
is very nasty and complex problem for real world software.
You may use WinDBG/Pageheap for identifying actual memory overrun in your program.

Comment: You are right, in other executions I am still having errors. Thanks for the tipo about WinDBG/Pageheap, I will try to find the memory error then.

Comment: I have noticed that it fails also without the delet []. Does this mean that the problem can be in other part of the program?

Comment: @cuartango, yes based on symptoms it looks like there could be memory overrun error in other part of your program. I think WinDBG/Pageheap would be helpful to understand it completely.......

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`dataRead += read(fd, (data+dataRead), BLOCK_SIZE);`

Are you accidentally assigning to same variable 'validEpsData' all 18 times, in which case you have memory leak. Where did u declare this variable?

```
validEpsData.loadFile(lpcTheFile3,dwFileSize,FT_BIT);
```

It should be:

```
validEpsData1.loadFile(lpcTheFile3,dwFileSize,FT_BIT);
......
validEpsData18.loadFile(lpcTheFile3,dwFileSize,FT_BIT);
```

destructor will not be called until you go out of scope of your main() or in other words quit the program

Comment: As you remarked, I was already assigning validEpsData to different variables. Finally I changed the way of reading the file. But thanks anyway.